# Templates in C#

Tags: c#, templates

I know generics are in C# to fulfill a role similar to C++ templates but I really need a way to generate some code at compile time - in this particular situation it would be very easy to solve the problem with C++ templates.

Does anyone know of any alternatives? Perhaps a VS plug-in that preprocesses the code or something like that? It doesn't need to be very sophisticated, I just need to generate some methods at compile time.

Here's a very simplified example in C++ (note that this method would be called inside a tight loop with various conditions instead of just "Advanced" and those conditions would change only once per frame - using if's would be too slow and writing all the alternative methods by hand would be impossible to maintain). Also note that performance is very important and that's why I need this to be generated at compile time.

```
template <bool Advanced>
int TraceRay( Ray r )
{
    do
    {
        if ( WalkAndTestCollision( r ) )
        {
            if ( Advanced )
                return AdvancedShade( collision );
            else
                return SimpleShade( collision );
        }
    }
    while ( InsideScene( r ) );
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you provide a code example of the C++ template you would use?  There may be an alternate approach that could accomplish what you want in C#.

Comment: Bear in mind, C# uses a JIT compiler.  So even `if` statements that are evaluated at "run time" can get optimized into compiled code by the JIT, as long as it can determine that only one path will ever be taken.  Plus, if you care about this level of performance, you shouldn't be using managed code in the first place.

Comment: I don`t believe the JIT compiler can do that kind of optimization at all because the path taken can change from one frame to another and the JIT only compiles when the code is first needed (if it did it would be even slower because it would spend a lot of time recompiling).

I`m aware using C++ would be better for this but it`s part of a much larger codebase in C# and I`d rather stick with that if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

**EDIT**:  In your example, you can use a simple `bool` parameter.

Comment: +1: This is probably the most feature-rich option presented so far. (Though some explanation would help too ;) )

Comment: T4 seems to do what I want, thanks! It`s not nearly as clean as C++ templates but it`s just one bottleneck class so I`m probably going with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, as far as I know. You can do this type of thing at *runtime*, of course; a few meta-programming options, none of them trivial:

- reflection (the simplest option if you don't need "fastest possible")
- CSharpCodeProvider and some code-generation
- the same with CodeDom
- ILGenerator if you want hardcore

Comment: Also PostSharp (www.sharpcrafters.com) is in the same category and could be used.

Comment: Unfortunately performance is essential so it has to be generated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Generics does work as templates, if that the case.
There is a way to create code in runtime -

Check is CodeProject Example:

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/Run-Time_Code_Generation1.aspx)

Comment: He wants to do this at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc's excellent suggestions, you may want to have a look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I've done some Meta-Programming - style tricks using static generics that use reflection (and now I'm using dynamic code generation using System.Linq.Expressions; as well having used ILGenerator for some more insane stuff).  http://www.lordzoltan.org/blog/post/Pseudo-Template-Meta-Programming-in-C-Sharp-Part-2.aspx for an example I put together (sorry about the lack of code formatting - it's a very old post!) that might be of use.

I've also used [T4](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creatating-your-first-code-generator/) (link goes to a series of tutorials by my favourite authority on T4 - Oleg Sych), as suggested by SLaks - which is a really nice way to generate code, especially if you're also comfortable with Asp.Net-style syntax.  If you generate partial classes using the T4 output, then the developer can then embellish and add to the class however they see fit.

If it absolutely has to be compile-time - then I'd go for T4 (or write your own custom tool, but that's a bit heavy).  If not, then a static generic could help, probably in partnership with the kind of solutions mentioned by Marc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want true code generation, you could use CodeSmith [http://www.codesmithtools.com](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) which isn't free/included like T4, but has some more features, and can function as a VS.NET plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an older article that uses genetic programming to generate and compile code on the fly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163934.aspx

"The Generator class is the kernel of the genetic programming application. It discovers available base class terminals and functions. It generates, compiles, and executes C# code to search for a good solution to the problem it is given. The constructor is passed a System.Type which is the root class for .NET reflection operations."

Might be overkill for your situation, but does show what C# can do. (Note this article is from the 1.0 days)